# How to subtract all column values of two PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Hi I faced this case that I need to subtract all column values between two PySpark dataframe like this:
df1:

```
col1 col2 ... col100
 1    2   ...  100
```

df2:

```
col1 col2 ... col100
5     4   ...  20
```

And I want to get the final dataframe with df1 - df2 :
new df:

```
col1 col2  ... col100
-4     -2  ...   80
```

I checked the possible solution is subtract two column like:

```
new_df = df1.withColumn('col1', df1['col1'] - df2['col1'])
```

But I have 101 columns, how can I simply traverse the whole thing and avoid writing 101 similar logics?
Any answers are super appriciate!

for 101 columns how to simply traverse all column and subtract its values?

Answer (score 0):

Within a single select with a python list comprehension :

```py
columns = df1.columns

df1 = df1.select(*(df1[col] - df2[col]).alias(col) for col in columns))
```

Comment: Hi Steven, does your solution impose somewhat more, or rather less efficient code (due to the list comprehension ? I'd tend to say, PySpark's query engine will optimize the calculation and minimize the overhead of using  'Python list comprehension'.
I am trying to learning something here .. Thank you..

Comment: @SoldOut The difference between this solution and yours is that `withColumn` check the validity each time it's called. My solution is using `select`, therefore, it checks the validity only once, hence faster. The output and spark computation time should be the same.